# Three questions about CSS in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

Three questions for CSS:

1. How to "derive" a translucent color from a color variable in css

```
* {
    -my-color: #123456;
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: ???
}
```

What do i put in "???" To get a 50% opacity version of -my-color. Should I use Java instead of CSS for this?

2. How to animate between colors from regular to hover state in CSS?

I want to change the color from e.g. red to blue whenever a button is hovered, but I do not want it to happen immediately. Should I use Java instead of CSS for this?

3. How to specify fallback fonts in CSS.

I want to ensure that both Japanese and Arabic fonts display with my font in TextFields. I can't find a way to achieve this.

EDIT: I have a Japanese font and an Arabic font, but I do not know what the user is going to enter in the TextField, but I want both languages to be displayed using my fonts

EDIT2: JavaFX's CSS is based on CSS 2.1

Comment: Are you versed in Sass? You can achieve what you want in CSS by decalring your colors via `hsla` and then `calc()` `a`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In general CSS does not have that functionality. You need some pre-processor, e.g. [Less](http://lesscss.org/) ([how to use in JavaFX](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/08/07/using-less-in-javafx/))

```
$myColor: #123456;

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: lighten($myColor, 50%)
}
```

2. Use `transition: color 300ms ease-in-out`

```css
.my-span {
  color: blue;
  transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.my-span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="my-span">Hover Me</span>
```

3. You specify multiple fonts with `,`: `font-family: MainFont, FallbackFont, FallbackFont2, Arial, Sans-Serif`

So if user browser does not have `MainFont` it will try to use `FallbackFont`, and so on until using most generic `Sans-Serif` font

Comment: If I use LESS or SASS I would get additional functionalities to JavaFX's CSS 2.1? How does that work?